# Create a flag parameter for having three products inside one agent (Anylogic)

Tags: anylogic, agent

I'm trying to create 3 different agent types inside one source. Given that creating three different agents with one source is not suggested, I'm trying to create a flag parameter in order to mark each spawning agent with a numeric parameter in order to have for each different typology the same route in the model but i.e. different process times (all these data will be read from an Excel file).

I created an agent population and I created the parameter inside the agent. But I'm not able to create a link beetween this parameter and the main model blocks in order to read the value from excel and having it updated in order to spawn a different product every time.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Ale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the keyword in the various flow chart code boxes, for example as below:
[image]

However, there is a lot of nuance (different keywords, sometimes not available, sometimes you need typecasting...). Here is what you should do:

1. do all AnyLogic [tutorials](https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html) (take 3-4 hrs max)
2. read about the [magic lightbulb](https://www.anylogic.com/blog/the-magic-light-bulb-by-benjamin-schumann/)
3. understand the basics of OOP and Java
4. build simple test models